# Terminating program if the right input is inserted

Tags: c++, if-statement, selection

So my problem is, I want to terminate the program if the right input was inserted, like A-E(big or smallcaps) and I want to ask them again the question if they input wrong letters like k,x,L. But my problem is, it wont stop asking even if the right letter is inputted.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
char letter;
char grades;
char A, B, C, D, E;
letter = A, B, C, D, E;
do{
cout << "\n Input grade letter: ";
cin >> letter;
if (letter=='A' || letter=='a')
{
    cout << "Your grade is in the range of 96-100";
}else if (letter=='B' || letter=='b')
{
    cout << "Your grade is in the range of 91-95";
}
else if (letter=='C' || letter=='c')
{
    cout << "Your grade is in the range of 86-90";
}
else if (letter=='D'|| letter=='d')
{
    cout << "Your grade is in the range of 80-85";
}
else if (letter=='E'|| letter=='e')
{
    cout << "Your grade is in the range of 79 and below";
}
else {
    cout << "Invalid Input! Try again!";
}
}while(letter==A, B, C, D, E);
///if the input correct
cout<< "\nBye";

return 0;
```

}

Comment: What exactly is this line supposed to do `letter = A, B, C, D, E;`? I think you have a very fundamental misunderstanding of the difference between variable names and `char` literals.

Comment: while(letter==A, B, C, D, E); doesn't do what you (probably) expect it does.

Comment: B C D E are evaluated to true by your , separation

Comment: There are multiple problems with the code but the linked questions is not a duplicate

Comment: What can I do with my code?

Comment: First learn a little more of the fundamental concepts of the language before you try to do something like this. You are just going to frustrate yourself with issues like this and other people with questions about issues like this if you don't first understand the basics of the language, its operators and syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code:

1. `char A, B, C, D, E;` does not assign any values to the variables `A, B, C, D, E`. It seems you expect they will be set to `'A'` `'B'` ... `'E'`.
2. `letter = A, B, C, D, E;` does not do what you seem to expect. `letter` is just a char, it can not hold multiple values. Consider using a data structure better suited for what you need, in particular [std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)
3. Similarly `while(letter==A, B, C, D, E);` does not check if letter is one of these values.